# all possible subsets in java in different sequences

Tags: java

I have a set =(1, 2, 3), and I need to get all possible subsets of set with different sequences (with repeating elements).The out put look:

```
1
2
3
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,3
3,1
3,2
1,2,3
1,3,2
2,1,3
2,3,1
3,1,2
3,2,1
```

please can someone help me with that? thxx

Comment: Use *[binary subsets](http://www.keithschwarz.com/binary-subsets/)* Also see *[this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/power-set.html)* link

Answer (score 3):

If you want **subsets**, then Google Guava has a method for you:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#powerSet(java.util.Set)

But in your example you have some duplicate sets (remember, sets are unordered). So you might want to get all the possible permutations of each subset as well:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#permutations(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 0):

The  problem can be solved by finding all combinations using bitwise operations.

The idea is: Generate all the subsets of a given array (set), this set is known as a power set .For each of the subset(Combination), find its permutation too.

Refer the following tutorials, to learn, how can you find all combinations using Bit Wise Operations. http://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-bitwise-operations

```
    void PERMUTE()
    {
        /*PERMUTATION FUNCTION THAT PERMUTES THE SUBSET ARRAY*/
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int Set[]={1,2,3};
        int n=Set.length;

       for (int i = 0; i <= (1 << n); ++i)
       {

           System.out.print("[");
           int subsetSz=0;
           int A[]=new int[100];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                if ((i & 1 << j)!=0)
                {
                    System.out.print(Set[j]+",");
                    A[subsetSz++]=Set[j];

                }
            }
            System.out.println("]");
            /*Permute the subset*/
            if(subsetSz>1)
            {
                PERMUTE(A);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, i try to write the permutation function but every time gives me error!!